How can I plot points along a function's curve such that their distribution is denser when y is higher?
Assume the function is normalized (ranged from 0 to 1), and has a limited domain (in my case -180 to 180). How may I plot points along the function's curve such that they are distributed based on the height of the function? I.e. I wish for there to be more points when the function is closer to 1, and less points when the function is closer to 0.

You can use (x+delta,y) to represent the next point to be plotted, where delta is a decreasing function of y.
